# Scrapy Selenium: extracts first link then throws error

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm working on a scaper that collects property information.

The original code works perfectly.

```
URL = "https://orion.lancaster.ne.gov/Property-Detail/PropertyQuickRefID/{}"

class huntsmanCSS(scrapy.Spider):

name = "huntsman"
allowed_domains = ["orion.lancaster.ne.gov"]
f = open('parcel_ids.txt')
start_urls = [URL.format(pid.strip()) for pid in f.readlines()]
   
def parse(self, response):
     
        yield {

            'propId': response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_tdPropertyID::text').extract_first(),
            'address': response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_tdPropertyAddress::text').extract_first(),
            'owner': response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_divOwnersLabel::text').extract_first(),
            'propertyClass': response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_tdGIPropertyClass::text').extract_first(),
            'hood':  response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_tdGINeighborhood::text').extract_first(),
            'buildType': response.css('#resImprovementTable0 > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first(),
            'improveType': response.css('#resImprovementTable0 > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first(),
            'yrBuilt': response.css('#resImprovementTable0 > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5)::text').extract_first(),
            'saleDate': response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_tblSalesHistoryData tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)::text').extract_first(),
            'TAV': response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_tdPropertyValueHeader::text').extract_first(),
            'price': response.css('#dnn_ctr388_View_tblSalesHistoryData > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5)::text').extract_first(),
            'sqFt': response.css('#resImprovementTable0 > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(6)::text').extract_first() 
      
         }
```

Using a list of all parcels, it adjusts the URL to go to the next page.

Broken Code:

There is a link to a pdf that is embedded in a javascript button.  The pdf contains more information that I want to scrape.

It will retrieve the first link but then throws errors.

```
URL = "https://orion.lancaster.ne.gov/Property-Detail/PropertyQuickRefID/{}"

class resDatasheetLink(scrapy.Spider):

name = "resDatasheetLink"
allowed_domains = ["orion.lancaster.ne.gov"]
f = open('residential.txt')
start_urls = [URL.format(pid.strip()) for pid in f.readlines()]

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    
    while True:
        try: 
            btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnDataSheet"]')))
            btn.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        time.sleep(5)
        link = self.driver.current_url
        self.driver.close()

        yield {

             'datasheet': link

        }
```

Error:

```
2021-12-30 10:40:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: 
Crawled (200) <GET 
https://orion.lancaster.ne.gov/Property- 
Detail/PropertyQuickRefID/R402438> (referer: None)
2021-12-30 10:40:36 
[selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] 
DEBUG: POST 
http://localhost:19113/session/5acb1d8f4ebdb13482ab40a67f846d1d/url {"url": "https://orion.lancaster.ne.gov/Property-Detail/PropertyQuickRefID/R402438"}
2021-12-30 10:40:36 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:19113 "POST /session/5acb1d8f4ebdb13482ab40a67f846d1d/url HTTP/1.1" 404 878
2021-12-30 10:40:36 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-12-30 10:40:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://orion.lancaster.ne.gov/Property-Detail/PropertyQuickRefID/R402438> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

Answer (score 0):

*`break`* will take you out of the *`while`* loop. You need to unindent the last few lines just below `try-except{}` and invoke `self.driver.close()` (preferably `self.driver.quit()`) line at the end of parsing as follows:

def parse(self, response):
self.driver.get(response.url)

```
while True:
    try: 
        btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnDataSheet"]')))
        btn.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
time.sleep(5)
link = self.driver.current_url

yield {

     'datasheet': link

}

self.driver.close()
```

Comment: You haven't told us about your usecase, still I tried tried to help you out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

based on the way the spider is configured the loop was the issue.

```
class rDataLink(scrapy.Spider):

name = "rDataLink"
allowed_domains = ["orion.lancaster.ne.gov"]
f = open('residential.txt')
start_urls = [URL.format(pid.strip()) for pid in f.readlines()]

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnDataSheet"]')))
    btn.click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 7).until(EC.url_changes(response.url))
    link = self.driver.current_url
    
    yield {

        'datasheet': link

    }
```